# Update a Column that has been added in the same script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a deployment script that needs to add a column, and then populate it with some data. I check if the column exists - if it doesn't I add it, and attempt to change the value.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   sys.columns WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND name = 'MyColumn')
    BEGIN

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable
        ADD MyColumn INT NULL

...

       UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = MyValue

END
```

However, the script fails (on pre-compile?) as it says that MyColumn doesn't exist.

The only way I can think of fixing this, is to change the UPDATE statement to dynamic SQL, and EXEC it that way.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because of the compilation.  One solution is dynamic SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql 'UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = MyValue';
```

If you take this path, then you should pass in the value as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your update statement out side of the **IF NOT EXISTS** condition.

**Reason :** If you have column already present in your table, then it will exit the condition and execute the update statement, else it will add the column and then perform the update. have a look at below code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   sys.columns WHERE  object_id = 
OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND name = 'MyColumn')
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable
    ADD MyColumn INT NULL

END

GO

UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = 1
GO
```

Comment: The probl m with his is that, if the column existed, I don’t want to run the update again, as the data may have changed from the default. I could maybe set a property based on the existance if the column. That might work.